# Django forms.SelectMultiple complains about choices

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to create a form consisting of a multiple select field which is used to select multiple instances of my Person model.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    choices = [(p.id, str(p)) for p in Person.objects.all()]
    my_field = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple, choices=choices)
```

The widget looks exactly like I want, but when I submit the form, it fails with the message

> Select a valid choice. ['2', '3'] is not one of the available choices.

What am I doing wrong? When removing the `widget=forms.SelectMultiple,` from the third line, it works, but then it's only a single select field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because `ChoiceField` expects a single choice.

If you want to allow multiple choices, use a [`MultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield).

```
my_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=choices)
```

Note you don't have to specify the widget, as it's `forms.SelectMultiple` by default.